# XSL Transformation: Adding optional attributes to an element

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to add attributes to a certain element only if the value is not empty. I am aware I can use templates and selectors to provide a static version of the element, therefore not needing the xsl:if, but I have 10+ elements and do not want to have to create every possible permutation.

It may still be possible to use templates, and that would be ideal if it's possible. If not, I am ok using xsl:if.

Source Xml:

```
<Test>
    <Attribute1>A</Attribute1>
    <Attribute3>B</Attribute3>
</Test>
```

Using the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Test">

            <xsl:element name="MyElement">

                    <xsl:attribute name="FirstAttribute">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Attribute1"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="SecondAttribute">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Attribute2"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:attribute name="ThirdAttribute">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Attribute3"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>

            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get an output that looks like this:

```
<MyElement FirstAttribute="A" SecondAttribute="" ThirdAttribute="B" />
```

But I want this:

```
<MyElement FirstAttribute="A" ThirdAttribute="B" />
```

I originally wanted to use a template of this sort:

```
<xsl:element name="MyElement">

  <xsl:if test="Attribute1 != ''"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="FirstAttribute">
      <xsl:value-of select="Attribute1"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="Attribute2 != ''"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="SecondAttribute">
      <xsl:value-of select="Attribute2"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="Attribute3 != ''"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="ThirdAttribute">
      <xsl:value-of select="Attribute3"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:element>
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
XslTransformException was unhandled by user code
Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added.
```

When I use this C# code to process it:

```
namespace XslTest
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using System.Xml.Xsl;

    class Program
    {
        private const string xmlSrcPath = "testXml.xml";
        private const string xslPath = "testXsl.xsl";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = Serialize(xmlSrcPath, xslPath);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string Serialize(string xmlFile, string xslTemplate)
        {
            var xmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var xmlFileStream = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Open);

            xmlFileStream.CopyTo(xmlMemoryStream);
            xmlMemoryStream.Flush();
            xmlMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlMemoryStream);
            var xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            var transformedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            xslCompiledTransform.Load(xslTemplate);

            var transformedWriter = new XmlTextWriter(transformedMemoryStream, null);
            xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xPathDoc, transformedWriter);

            transformedMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var transformedReader = new StreamReader(transformedMemoryStream);
            return transformedReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this kind of operation?

Comment: You must code an identity transform (copy all input to output) and do the modifications as the node is being copied.

Comment: I don't think you show the code that causes the error. The issue is that you cannot add an attribute after you wrote a non-attribute node for a given element. So make sure that you write all attributes first and only then write contents.

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . ---  "*I have 10+ elements and do not want to have to create every possible permutation.*" I suspect you could use a single template here, instead of 10+ `xsl:if` statements in series. But we need a clearer definition of the problem for this too.

Comment: You still haven't provided a reproducible example. Using only your code, there is no error - see: http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6q

Comment: It seems I may have misidentified the root cause of the problem and removed it when simplifying my code. I will work on this and find the root cause when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for your problem is using an `xsl:key` mapping between the element names and the desired target attribute name. In this illustration I included the `attr` mapping in the data file, but it can be outsourced to a new XML-document and then included as a data source. I modified the XSLT appropriately to this illustration needs. Here comes the XML with the mapping:

```
<Root>
    <attr elemName="Attribute1" attribName="FirstAttribute" />
    <attr elemName="Attribute2" attribName="SecondAttribute" />
    <attr elemName="Attribute3" attribName="ThirdAttribute" />
    <Test>
        <Attribute1>A</Attribute1>
        <Attribute3>B</Attribute3>
    </Test>
</Root>
```

The `xsl:for-each` in `xsl:element` iterates over all elements and compares their names to the ones defined in the `attr` nodes `elemName` attributes with the key-mapping. The curly braces around the expression are needed to evaluate the expression and not interpret it as a literal string. The `xsl:key` in the stylesheet uses the `attr` nodes from the XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="AllAttributes" match="attr" use="@elemName"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <xsl:for-each select="Test">
            <xsl:element name="MyElement">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{key('AllAttributes',local-name())/@attribName}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```